# Entity Framework - Composite Primary Key formed by 3 Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

i'm creating a relation between 4 tables: Provider, CostumerSite, DrmType and Drm.

Relation:
[image]

in the Drm table there is a composite key formed by the primary keys of the other 3 tables.. this is the Code:

```
public partial class Provider
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // one-to-many
    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }

    public virtual Drm Drm { get; set; }

}

 public partial class CustomerSite
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomerSiteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // many-to-many
    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }

    // one-to-one
    public virtual Drm Drm { get; set; }
}

 public partial class DrmType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DrmTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // one-to-one
    public virtual Drm Drm { get; set; }
}

public partial class Drm
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DrmId { get; set; }

    // one-to-one relation
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("CustomerSite")]
    public int CustomerSiteId { get; set; }

    // one-to-one relation
    [Key,  Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Provider")]
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }

    // one-to-one relation
    [Key,  Column(Order = 3), ForeignKey("DrmType")]
    public int DrmTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Provider Provider { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerSite CustomerSite { get; set; }
    public virtual DrmType DrmType { get; set; }
}
```

Is this correct? After this, i'm using the onModel function:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Drm>()
        .HasKey(d => new { d.ProviderId, d.CustomerSiteId, d.DrmType });

    }
```

But in this way, when i launch the "Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force" command it shows an error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Drm_CustomerSite_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'Drm_CustomerSite_Source' in relationship 'Drm_CustomerSite'. Because
>   the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper
>   bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
>   Drm_Provider_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'Drm_Provider_Source' in relationship 'Drm_Provider'. Because the
>   Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound
>   of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Can you explain how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: There is no `1:1` relation in reality, it is always `0-1:1`, one side of relation has to be optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your model, `Drm` should not have its own "id". So, it should look like this:

```
public partial class Drm
{
    //remove this property
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    //public int DrmId { get; set; }

    // one-to-one relation
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("CustomerSite")]
    public int CustomerSiteId { get; set; }

    // one-to-one relation
    [Key,  Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Provider")]
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }

    // one-to-one relation
    [Key,  Column(Order = 3), ForeignKey("DrmType")]
    public int DrmTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Provider Provider { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerSite CustomerSite { get; set; }
    public virtual DrmType DrmType { get; set; }
}
```

Since you provided the `[Key]` attribute at the class declaration, you do not need to declare `HasKey` in the model binding. So, remove this line:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Drm>()
    .HasKey(d => new { d.ProviderId, d.CustomerSiteId, d.DrmType });
```

**EDIT**

`Provider`, `CustomerSite` and `DrmType` must have a collection of `Drm`.

```
public partial class Provider
{
    //...
    //public virtual Drm Drm { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Drm> Drms { get; set; }
}

public partial class CustomerSite
{
    //...
    //public virtual Drm Drm { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Drm> Drms { get; set; }
}

public partial class DrmType
{
    //public virtual Drm Drm { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<Drm> Drms { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But this solution is for a 1 to n relation... in my project i have created a 1 to 1 realtion...

Comment: Your image shows a 1 to n relationship. The `Drm` PK is composed by 3 FKs. So, it can't be a 1 to 1. The only way to achieve 1-1 is when the both tables share the same primary key, which is not your case. The Drm's PK is different from all others entities. See this link for further instructions http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is by giving the DRM table its own ID and making the  3 fields Foreign keys.
I do not know to what extend you are normalising but it is something often done to prevent unnecessary complex code.
keep it clean, keep it simple